# Microsoft Graph Mail API with $search filter not working when we check received time is greater

Tags: rest, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am working with

> Microsoft Graph API

I have a requirement to get emails with different filters and with the specified time range. I am using Odata query for the filter, a couple of examples are:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<Email-id>/<folder-id>/messages?$search="received>2019-07-02T07:16:39.094Z AND received<2019-07-02T07:17:39.095Z AND isRead=false"


https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<Email-id>/<folder-id>/messages?$search="received>2019-07-02T07:16:39.094Z AND received<2019-07-02T07:17:39.095Z AND isRead=false AND body:testbody"
```

Till the morning it was working fine, but now I am facing the **504 Gateway timeout** issue

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "f3ecaf3d-e9c2-4b99-8a01-224de9852d57",
        "date": "2019-07-02T11:38:20"
    }
}
```

After spending some time I observed there is an issue with below filter with the greater sign.

```
received>2019-07-02T07:16:39.094Z
```

If I remove this, then this will work fine. It works fine with the less sign as well.

```
received<2019-07-02T07:17:39.095Z
```

Any idea team why it stops working?

Comment: One finding here, This is not specific to a field, we got this error when there is no data available. It seems a problem from Microsoft graph API

Comment: This seems to be a general issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/56880644/2339622

Answer (score 1):

The graph api doesn’t like the > in the url. Just replace it with `gt`.

`received gt 2021-01-01...`

Complete sample on the odata [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) page.

```
https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime+ge+2017-04-01+and+receivedDateTime+lt+2017-05-01&method=GET&version=v1.0
```

I would just combine both the $search and filter parameter.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64134415/639153

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it uses $filter instead of $search which handles ge differently.