# How to specify time in Azure AD Sign In REST API request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I need to retrieve the data after a specific period of time in order to avoid duplication. I can filter out based on the date. On filtering based on today's date, there is repetition in signIn data for the date for consequent requests

I have tried the filtering criteria for the following API
Ref link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Sample Request I have tried : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?&$filter=createdDateTime gt 2020-09-29

I need to specify the time in this request...Any ideas ..?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track! The filter you're using also accepts a time.

If you check the [List sign-in response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1) you'll see the format Microsoft uses to specify the date and the time in out field.

Try this URI (for all items after 2020-09-29 19:00:00 (UTC as noted by the **z** at the end)):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?&$filter=createdDateTime gt 2020-09-29T19:00:00z`